# How to decrypt plain text x using man in the middle attack

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption, man-in-the-middle

Suppose Alice want to share a plain text $x = 5$ to Bob; using RSA, DHKE, and El-Gamal.

My question is if Man-in-the-middle attack is applied then weather oscar can compute/decrypt plain text in all of the algorithms if yes then let me how Oscar will decrypt the plain text using the following information

- In RSA: $p= 3, q=11, d=7, e=3$
- In Elgamal: $\alpha= 2. p=29$, Alice key $A=3$, Bob Key $B=7$
- In DHKE: $\alpha= 2, p=29$, Alice key $A=3$, Bob Key $B=7$

Please let me how Oscar will get the plain text $x = 5$

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks its an assignment and research problem, I have tried using RSA but can't get the plain text at Oscar end

Comment: You can use $\LaTeX$ here with Mathjax. Edit your question to show your work, so we can help you.